# Do I need MySite Web App per UPSA?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, my-site

In SP2013 farm I have 2 User Profile Service Applications (UPSA) running and working fine.

UPSA1 -->  Using SharePoint Synchronization >> associate with WebApp1

UPSA2 --> Using ADI >> Associate with WebAPP2

One MySiteWebApp mentioned in both UPSAa in " mnage MySite.

Q1 : Do I need My site web app per UPSA? or can single MySiteWebApp work with multiple UPSAs?

Q2 : If I add an item in column " User or Group" picture shows up for user in WebApp1 , If I add an item in same column in WebApp2 user picture does not show up here. I am using script to download and sync pictures for UPSA2. and its the same mysite that has pictures in " user photos" folder. 
Any advise why pictures don't show up in WebApp2 using UPSA2 (ADI)

Thanks